# Using setInterval in for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm currently facing a little Problem in AS3. What I want to achieve is to fade images in a for loop. The problem is that the loop is not waiting for the setInterval function to be finished.

```
for(var i in imageClips){
    setInterval(function(){
        fade(imageClips[i]);
    }, 6000);        
}
```

The behavior is clear once the setInterval function is called the loop just goes on. My question now is, is there a way to make the loop wait to be done with the things happening in the setInterval function?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` does not delay the loop execution. You can do this:

```
function fadeImages(imageClips) {
  // Create a clone
  var imageStack:Array = imageClips.concat();

  // Create the callback that will fade all images
  var doFade:Function = function() {
    if (imageStack.length > 0) {
      fade(imageStack.shift());
      setInterval(doFade, 6000);
    }
  }

  // Start fading images
  doFade();
}

// Fade specified images
fadeImages(imageClips);
```

If you want to do the fade again, just again the function.

**Edit:** Wrapped the snippet with a function.

Comment: Better off to use `Timer` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: Altough this solution works fine I cannot figure out a way to repeat the fading unlimited times. I tried to push the array with the element I shift but this does not work. One iteration works fine but after that the images begin to fade too fast. Could you help me out with this once again? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll make your life a whole lot easier if you use a library such as Greensocks' [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) for your tweens. It's pretty much the standard for programmatic animation in Flash and provides a staggering number of features including the ability to set a delay on a tween.

Using TweenMax, your code would look something like this:

```
var delay:int = 6; // delay between fades in seconds
var duration:int = 1; // duration of fade in seconds

for (var i in imageClips) 
{
    TweenMax.to(imageClips[i], duration, { alpha: 0, delay: i * delay });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use events instead of waiting for the animation to end. Dispatch a complete event at the end of each animation (for instance on the last frame of a MovieClip):

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

Then add listeners to each animation:

```
var index:int = -1;

function fadeNext(event:Event = null):void {
    index += 1;
    if (index < imageClips.length) fade(imageClips[index]);
}

for (var i in imageClips) {
    imageClips[i].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fadeNext, false, 0, true);
}

fadeNext();
```

This way you can change the duration of your animations without the need to synchronize any timeouts.